# Can't visit my app through canvas page url

Tags: facebook, canvas

I am trying to design an canvas app on facebook. At the beginning, it worked fine, and I can visit and test my demo by clicking the bookmark on my facebook page and entering the canvas page url like "https://apps.facebook.com/namespace/". But recently it stopped working.

It only shows the facebook frame with an error blank page showing the browser can't connect to my server. But I can visit the website for my app on my own server remotely by entering the url like "http://my domain/index.html". What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an SSL certificate on your server so that Facebook can load your page in an iframe over HTTPS.  You also will need to enter the secure URL of your app in the app settings.

Comment: Thanks, Fisch. I sovlved the problem by deactivating the secure browsing in my facebook account settings. Account settings->security settings->secure browsing.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem, though, it just temporarily hides it for you - HTTPS users still can't reach your app